# Android project cannot run in myeclipse

Tags: java, android, myeclipse

I create a HelloWorld Android application project.

When run this project,myEclipse tells me :
com/android/dx/command/dexer/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0.

The problem seems to be a jar version conflict. 
In the beginning ,I use JDK1.7.

For trying To solve this problem ,I change to JDK1.8.
However,it doesn't work.Could anyone help me to get out?
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are now using 2 JDK which causes this error. Because when code is written in a jdk version and run in another version. It causes problem.

1. First Uninstall JDK 7 and install JDK 8.
2. you can create another project and rewrite the code.

Hope it will help your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some classes used by the builder were compiled for Java 8 but you're running the builder with Java 7. Go to the Window->Preferences->MyEclipse->Mobile Tools->PhoneGap Build->Local Build and ensure that JDK 8 is set. If that doesn't work, you'd need to include a lot more detail about your MyEclipse version, your Mobile Tools and workspace Java setting and exactly how you are building.

Another option is to build remotely using the Phonegap build service.

Answer (score 0):

Open your project File project.properties :

```
sdk.buildtools=23.0.3
```

Or last version